# unordered_set custom hash via lambdas

Tags: c++, hash, visual-studio-2017, unordered-set

I can implement custom hash function via functors no problem. However when trying to compile this code

```
class Student {
public:
    string fname;
    string lname;
    Student(string f, string l) : fname(f), lname(l) {}
};

int main()
{
    Student a("John", "Doe");
    auto StudentHash = [](const Student& obj) -> const size_t 
         {return (std::hash<string>()(obj.fname) ^ std::hash<string>()(obj.lname)); };
    auto StudentEqual = [](const Student& lhs, const Student& rhs) -> const bool 
         {return (lhs.fname == rhs.fname && lhs.lname == rhs.lname);};
    unordered_set<Student, decltype(StudentHash), decltype(StudentEqual)> st;
    st.insert(a);
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Error   C2280   'main::<lambda_a8a8645443a5445869be61b46baaf9d3>::<lambda_a8a8645443a5445869be61b46baaf9d3>(void)': attempting to reference a deleted function
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: In case you haven't tried (and if you have, it should be part of your question), this will compile if you actually specified the initial bucket prime, hash, and equals as *constructor* arguments. If you *did* try that, then isn't your question really, "Why doesn't unordered_set know how to construct my hasher and equalcheck when I gave it the types to do so?"

Comment: Yes it works. Thank you!

unordered_set<Student, decltype(StudentHash), decltype(StudentEqual)> st(8, StudentHash, StudentEqual);

Comment: If the posted answer answers your question, please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/627709) it. Doing so rewards the volunteer who wrote it with a token reputation reward, and provides information to future visitors that the question was in fact resolved.

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide the `Hash` and `KeyEqual` objects to the constructor of the `unordered_set`, like this:

```
unordered_set<Student, decltype(StudentHash), decltype(StudentEqual)> st(0, StudentHash, StudentEqual);
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/LVEtqh).